# Ubuntu Upgrade settings

Tags: upgrade

I have Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS installed in VMWare. Now I have Apache Hadoop and Apache Spark installed in it. A pop up menu has come up offering me to upgrade to Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS. I am willing to upgrade. However, I am worried that if I upgrade to version 20.04, I may lose the Hadoop and Spark settings.

So this is my question: If I upgrade to Ubuntu 20.x from my present version which already has Hadoop and Spark configured/installed in it, will I lose these settings, and will I have to re-install/re-configure once I upgrade to the new Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to answer this question 100% accurately without knowing all of the various settings, tweaks, and customisations you have made to your system over the last few years is to try it. This is not as risky as you might think, because you said that the Ubuntu Desktop installation is running in a VM. This gives you the ability to "rollback" if things go sour.

This is what I do when updating VMs:

1. Clone the VM
2. Upgrade the clone
3. Test the clone

So long as the clone is good, then I use the clone. If it's no good, I delete the clone and continue using the original. The nice thing about this is that if I ever need to go back to the previous version for whatever reason, the old VM is sitting there waiting.

VMs are "cheap". Don't be afraid to clone/delete/destroy them to test a theory